# Meaning of "見るとこは見てくれてる"

Tags: meaning

Context: A and B are talking about B's son, 景明

A:「景明を信じて託すと云うのか」

B:「うん」

A:「……儂とて奴には信を置くところがある。　でなくば冗談にも山賊退治を命じたりなどせん」

B:「あぁ。あんたも**見るとこは見てくれてる**な。　母親としちゃ、嬉しいことだ」

What does "見るとこは見てくれてる" mean in this case? I suspect it's something like "paying attention to the right things" (Kageaki's aptitude in this case) but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. This 見るとこ is the same as 見るところ, or "points to see", referring to Kageaki's good points (traits) people should be aware of. It's interchangeable with 見るべきところ. は is a contrast marker that replaced を; here it adds the nuance of "at least".